# Django 'exclude' query did not return expected results

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am relatively new to Django and this is my first post in the forum.

Below are the models(simplified) that are used in the app.
The app is about reserving a set of resources for a given period.

```
from django.db import models

class Resource(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    serialno = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False)    

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}/{self.serialno}"

class Reservations(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    startdate = models.DateField(null=False)
    enddate = models.DateField(null=False)    
    resource = models.ManyToManyField("myapp.Resource", db_table="myapp_resource_reservations", related_name="reservations")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}/{self.startdate}/{self.enddate}"
```

For example, below are the data present in the models

Resource(format: name/serialno)

```
>>> Resource.objects.all()
  
<QuerySet [<Resource: Resource1/RES1>, <Resource: Resource2/RES2>, <Resource: Resource3/RES3>, <Resource: Resource4/RES4>]>
>>>
```

Reservations(format: name/startdate/enddate/active)
All reservations are made for Resource1

```
>>> Reservations.objects.all()
 
<QuerySet [<Reservations: Booking1/2023-03-01/2023-03-07/True>, <Reservations: Booking2/2023-03-15/2023-03-22/True>, <Reservations: BookingX/2023-03-08/2023-03-14/False>]>
>>>
```

I am trying to retrieve all resources that do not have an 'active' reservation for a given date period using below query.

```
>>> Resource.objects.exclude((Q(reservations__startdate__range=('2023-03-08','2023-03-14')) | Q(reservations__enddate__range=('2023-03-08','2023-03-14'))) & Q(reservations__active=True))
  
<QuerySet [<Resource: Resource2/RES2>, <Resource: Resource3/RES3>, <Resource: Resource4/RES4>]>
>>>
```

Resource1 does have a reservation: BookingX for period 2023-03-08 to 14 but it is active=False. I expected 'Resource1' to show up in above exclude query but it didn't (intended logic: 'exclude all resources that fall in the date range with an active=True reservation').

Can someone help understand why the results are not as expected ? What am I doing wrong ?

Tried using 'filter' instead of 'exclude', it behaves as expected.

```
>>> Resource.objects.filter((Q(reservations__startdate__range=('2023-03-08','2023-03-14')) | Q(reservations__enddate__range=('2023-03-08','2023-03-14'))) & Q(reservations__active=True))
  
<QuerySet []>
>>>
>>> Resource.objects.filter((Q(reservations__startdate__range=('2023-03-08','2023-03-14')) | Q(reservations__enddate__range=('2023-03-08','2023-03-14'))) & Q(reservations__active=False)) 

<QuerySet [<Resource: Resource1/RES1>]>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically telling the ORM to exclude all Resource's that have ANY active reservations. Because `&` is evaluated first (before `|`) it doesn't really matter what is in the ranges as it has already excluded Resource 1 at that point.

Comment: I added an active reservation for resource RES2 for period '2023-03-01/2023-03-07' and ran the same exclude query, I don't see RES2 getting excluded.

Comment: I do; `Resource.objects.exclude((Q(reservations__active=True)))` results in `<QuerySet [<Resource: Resource3/RES3>, <Resource: Resource4/RES4>]>`, its easier to see what happends if you omit the date filter and just use the active filter

Comment: It seems you could just use a simple query and omit Q objects in this case, eg; Resource.objects.exclude(reservations__active=True, reservations__startdate__lte='2023-03-XX', reservations__enddate__gte='2023-03-XX')

Comment: Thanks for responding, I am still trying to wrap my mind around the behavior. What would be correct query to achieve my intent ?

Comment: I think I figured it out `Resource.objects.exclude(reservations__in = Reservations.objects.filter((Q(startdate__range=('2023-03-08','2023-03-14')) | Q(enddate__range=('2023-03-08','2023-03-14'))) & Q(active=True) ) )`. This query gets what I want. Basically I understand any arguments passed to 'exclude' will be excluded even if they don't occur together in the same row.